# MMULT formula not working with a VBA function

Tags: vba, excel

I created a VBA function `=cellrange(some inputs here)` that yields an array (i.e. `$AD$3:$AP$346`)

In this example I am using the following formula in order to get a matrix: `=MMULT(TRANSPOSE($AD$3:$AP$345),$AD$3:$AP$345)` and I get the correct response.

When I use my VBA function:
`=MMULT(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT(cellrange(A3,"all",COLUMN(AD2)-1,COLUMN(AP2)-1))),INDIRECT(cellrange(A3,"all",COLUMN(AD2)-1,COLUMN(AP2)-1)))`

**Question:** Why do I get an error and how can this be fixed?

P.S. I have used this function sucessfully many times before, however not in a `=MMULT()`

**VBA function code:** [there is nothing wrong here as far as I know, but I have provided it for reference]

```
Option Explicit

Public Function cellrange(rDates As Range, vFilter As Variant, Optional colOffsetA As Variant, Optional colOffsetB As Variant) As String
'DESCRIPTION:
    'This function takes any cell value in a row and a input: YTD, ALL, or any year (i.e. 2014, 2015) and it finds the range in which the date is situated

    Dim i As Long, ndx1 As Long, ndx2 As Long, r As Range, vA As Variant, bErr As Boolean, bAll As Boolean
    bErr = True
    If IsDate(rDates) Then
        With rDates.EntireColumn
            i = rDates.Parent.Evaluate("count(" & .Address & ")")
            Set r = .Cells(1 - i + rDates.Parent.Evaluate("index(" & .Address & ",match(9.9E+307," & .Address & "))").Row).Resize(i, 1)
        End With
        vA = r.Value
        If IsMissing(colOffsetA) And IsMissing(colOffsetB) Then
            colOffsetA = 0: colOffsetB = 0
        End If
        If IsMissing(colOffsetB) = True Then colOffsetB = colOffsetA
        Select Case LCase(vFilter)
            Case "all"
                bErr = 0: bAll = 1
                Set r = r.Range(r.Parent.Cells(1, 1 + colOffsetA), r.Parent.Cells(r.Count, 1 + colOffsetB))
            Case "ytd"
                For i = 1 To UBound(vA)
                    If ndx1 = 0 And Year(vA(i, 1)) = Year(Date) Then ndx1 = i
                    If vA(i, 1) <= Date Then ndx2 = i
                Next
            Case Else 'year
                vFilter = Val(vFilter)
                If vFilter Then
                    For i = 1 To UBound(vA)
                        If ndx1 = 0 And Year(vA(i, 1)) = vFilter Then ndx1 = i
                        If ndx1 And Year(vA(i, 1)) = vFilter Then ndx2 = i
                    Next
                End If
        End Select
        If Not bAll Then If ndx1 > 0 And ndx2 > 0 Then Set r = r.Range(r.Parent.Cells(ndx1, 1 + colOffsetA), r.Parent.Cells(ndx2, 1 + colOffsetB)): bErr = False
        If Not bErr Then cellrange = r.Address Else cellrange = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    Else
        cellrange = CVErr(xlErrValue) 'check if this is the correct error handling
    End If
End Function
```

**Support Photo:**
[image]

Comment: This most likely has something to do with INDIRECT rather than MMULT.

Comment: When you F9 on your UDF inside the formula what does it return?
Also When you do the same F9 on INDIRECT what do you get?

Comment: When using my VBA function, it needs to be used with indirect (at least I have done so successfully in previous experiences), in order to yield an answer.

Comment: I am not sure about your Q, but either way when I press F9 nothing happens.

Comment: When you are inside the formula edit mode, simply highlight cellrange(A3,"all",COLUMN(AD2)-1,COLUMN(AP2)-1) and press F9 and see what you get as result. Do the same for INDIRECT(cellrange(A3,"all",COLUMN(AD2)-1,COLUMN(AP2)-1))

Comment: When I do this inside the MMULT, I get #VALUE, when I do it with Indirect inside the MMUL, obv. I get #VALUE again, however when I copy and past the formula (without Indirect) in another cell, I get the array I want, so that's why I don't understand what's wrong...

Comment: Do you get an array or text range? Can you post exactly what it outputs when you F9 on cellrange function?

Comment: I have now added a photo showing this.

Comment: can you add Application.Volatile line inside of your UDF right after Function declaration line and see if you have the same issue?

Comment: Could you please past the code before, as I think I may be adding it in the wrong place?

Comment: Public Function cellrange(rDates As Range, vFilter As Variant, Optional colOffsetA As Variant, Optional colOffsetB As Variant) As String
'DESCRIPTION:
    'This function takes any cell value in a row and a input: YTD, ALL, or any year (i.e. 2014, 2015) and it finds the range in which the date is situated

Application.Volatile

Comment: No change unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Change your cellrange function with NEWCELLRANGE and remove INDIRECT functions. See if it works.

```
Public Function NEWCELLRANGE(rDates As Range, vFilter As Variant, Optional colOffsetA As Variant, Optional colOffsetB As Variant) As String
'DESCRIPTION:
'This function takes any cell value in a row and a input: YTD, ALL, or any year (i.e. 2014, 2015) and it finds the range in which the date is situated

Dim i As Long, ndx1 As Long, ndx2 As Long, r As Range, vA As Variant, bErr As Boolean, bAll As Boolean
bErr = True
If IsDate(rDates) Then
    With rDates.EntireColumn
        i = rDates.Parent.Evaluate("count(" & .Address & ")")
        Set r = .Cells(1 - i + rDates.Parent.Evaluate("index(" & .Address & ",match(9.9E+307," & .Address & "))").Row).Resize(i, 1)
    End With
    vA = r.Value
    If IsMissing(colOffsetA) And IsMissing(colOffsetB) Then
        colOffsetA = 0: colOffsetB = 0
    End If
    If IsMissing(colOffsetB) = True Then colOffsetB = colOffsetA
    Select Case LCase(vFilter)
        Case "all"
            bErr = 0: bAll = 1
            Set r = r.Range(r.Parent.Cells(1, 1 + colOffsetA), r.Parent.Cells(r.Count, 1 + colOffsetB))
        Case "ytd"
            For i = 1 To UBound(vA)
                If ndx1 = 0 And Year(vA(i, 1)) = Year(Date) Then ndx1 = i
                If vA(i, 1) <= Date Then ndx2 = i
            Next
        Case Else 'year
            vFilter = Val(vFilter)
            If vFilter Then
                For i = 1 To UBound(vA)
                    If ndx1 = 0 And Year(vA(i, 1)) = vFilter Then ndx1 = i
                    If ndx1 And Year(vA(i, 1)) = vFilter Then ndx2 = i
                Next
            End If
    End Select
    If Not bAll Then If ndx1 > 0 And ndx2 > 0 Then Set r = r.Range(r.Parent.Cells(ndx1, 1 + colOffsetA), r.Parent.Cells(ndx2, 1 + colOffsetB)): bErr = False
    If Not bErr Then NEWCELLRANGE = evaluate(r) Else NEWCELLRANGE = CVErr(xlErrValue)
Else
    NEWCELLRANGE = CVErr(xlErrValue) 'check if this is the correct error handling
End If
End Function
```